# Get IP address location from windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, geolocation, ip

I have seen many questions and answer  on **stackoverflow**  regarding **how to  fetch geolocation of an IP address in asp.net** but..

How can  I fetch the IP address location in **winforms** ?

I am working on the **C# winform** application and I need to show user ,its **ip address** and **Its location**.
I am able to show user's Local,External IP address but I  could  not find any way to show Location.

Any body knows if I can do this with  any `WebRequest` or any other solution ?

**Edit:** I am able to accomplish the task by following method.

1. Send IP address to a site which shows location from the IP address.(e.g. www.whatismyipaddress.com)
2. fetching its source code.
3. parsing its code and use `string` operations to get the location.

But I know It is not  good approach as if website is down or moved or any change in the source code will make my code useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IpInfo](http://ipinfo.io/) is nice service for IP related things. They also have [a nice API](http://ipinfo.io/developers).

In the code below, I will make a web request to this service and it will return the IP info.

This will return your IP info:

```
public static string GetLocation(string ip)
{
    var res = "";
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://ipinfo.io/" + ip);
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            res += line;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

An example using this is:

```
Console.WriteLine (GetLocation("8.8.8.8"));
```

This will output:

> `{  "ip": "8.8.8.8",  "hostname": "No Hostname",  "city": "Mountain View",  "region": "California",  "country": "US",  "loc": "37.3860,-122.0838",  "org": "AS15169 Google Inc.",  "postal": "94035"}`

Comment: Hey,Thanks a lot. Nice method.

Comment: You are welcome. Thank you! I worked for it yesterday. :D Hope that you mark it (again) if I helped you.

Comment: actually i wanted something which will work every time. In case if maxmind is down tmrw,i wanted this to work. But i am accepting this as an answer because it's something which is exactly i needed.

Comment: Thank you. I thought at this... but I think that you understood the idea of it. :)

Comment: @Ionică :am getting a web exception on running this code.

Comment: @jincyabraham Yeah, probably that was outdated. I updated it with code that works.

Comment: @ Ionică : thanks :) i got this from another site. Web Request to this same site :)thanks for updating

Comment: how to get these all info in Label, like i want to store hostname in lbl_hostname and city in lblcity and all the same?

Comment: @user3441151 You have to [parse the response string as JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6620165/1420197) and get the needed fields. Also, a hacky way would be to search for `"hostname"` in the string and take the value that comes after the `: "` snippet.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [IP address geolocation database](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php)

Comment: Depends how much info you need. THe cost is not that high, though - well worth paying.

Comment: Yes IPInfoDB.com offers free services and they have just introduced their new Lite Version database, you will need to request for API key before you can download anything from there.

Comment: day b4 yesterday there were 3 answers for the same question and today u all can see only  one answer ..do we have new feature on stackoverflow to remove answers ??? Im confused  :O